# Merging associative array values where keys match within the same array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am generating an associative array that I want to use to generate a JSON object but have a problem of duplicate keys with different values. I want the where the keys are duplicate, the values of are merged. I have checked online but all the solutions reference 2 different arrays not the same array.

The JSON Object is:

```
{
  "trailervideos": [
    {
      "category": "Video Games",
      "videos": {
        "description": "Trailer of the game Dark Souls II",
        "title": "Dark Souls 2 Announcement Trailer"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "Video Games",
      "videos": {
        "description": "Trailer of the DLC Scholar of the First Sin for the game Dark Souls II",
        "title": "Dark Souls II Scholar of the First Sin - Forlorn Hope Trailer"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "Video Games",
      "videos": {
        "description": "Trailer of the DLC Ashes of Ariendel for the game Dark Souls III",
        "title": "Dark Souls III Ashes of Ariandel - Announcement Trailer PS4"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment",
      "videos": {
        "description": "",
        "title": "intro"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is all the values of repeated key "Video Games" combined so that I can generate a JSON object like:

```
{"trailervideos":[{"category":"Video Games","videos":[{"description":"Trailer of the game Dark Souls II","title":"Dark Souls 2 Announcement Trailer"},{"description":"Trailer of the DLC Scholar of the First Sin for the game Dark Souls II","title":"Dark Souls II Scholar of the First Sin - Forlorn Hope Trailer"},{"description":"Trailer of the DLC Ashes of Ariendel for the game Dark Souls III","title":"Dark Souls III Ashes of Ariandel - Announcement Trailer PS4"}],{"category":"Entertainment","videos":{"description":"","title":"intro"}}]}
```

Comment: Your target JSON is not valid JSON. Please have it validated first and then post the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'JSON-object'. JSON is a string reprentation a ***J***avas**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation you can build a PHP object-array-structure from, using `json_decode`. To get a JSON string from PHP variables, the function `json_encode` is used.

The easiest way is to iterate over the `trailervideos` building a new associative array since there can only be unique keys. We can eleminate the key names by the function `array_values` later to prevent `json_encode` from building an object instead of an array because associative arrays do not exist in JavaScript.

This version does process *all* categories, `"Video Games"` as well as `"Entertainment"` and, if available, even more.

```
$a = [];

foreach (($o = json_decode($json))->trailervideos as $v)
{
  isset($a[$v->category]) || $a[$v->category] = new stdClass();
  $a[$v->category]->category = $v->category;
  $a[$v->category]->videos[] = $v->videos;
}

$o->trailervideos = array_values($a);

var_dump(json_encode($o));
```

The (formatted) JSON result looks like that:

```
{
  "trailervideos": [
    {
      "category": "Video Games",
      "videos": [
        {
          "description": "Trailer of the game Dark Souls II",
          "title": "Dark Souls 2 Announcement Trailer"
        },
        {
          "description": "Trailer of the DLC Scholar of the First Sin for the game Dark Souls II",
          "title": "Dark Souls II Scholar of the First Sin - Forlorn Hope Trailer"
        },
        {
          "description": "Trailer of the DLC Ashes of Ariendel for the game Dark Souls III",
          "title": "Dark Souls III Ashes of Ariandel - Announcement Trailer PS4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment",
      "videos": [
        {
          "description": "",
          "title": "intro"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Quasimodo's clone, worked. My problem started with how I was building the initial associative array before encoding it. Messed up with a foreach loop. Thanks once again